# Number of occurrences stream

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have problem with number of occurrences from stream.

My code is :

```
f = open('xyz.txt')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    parts=line.split()
    for part in parts:
        i=0
        if parts.count("2017"):
            i+=1
```

What I can do to show how many times this number is on file xyz.txt ? I know it will be easy question but i search many information and cannot solve it. Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT**: In file `xyz.txt` I have these columns:

```
Name          Date
2017 AA     2017 Jun  4
```

What I can do to show how many times is date '2017'?

Comment: The biggest problem is that your columns are separated by spaces, *and* the values in the columns contain spaces. This complicates the problem. Update the line in your code to `parts=line.split()[1:]` and it should work.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston: Assuming the date is reliably in three pieces, you could do: `name, year, month, day = line.rsplit(None, 3)`, which would be store all data prior to the year as a single value.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0 
with open('wyz.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
          if "2017" in line:
               i = i + 1
```

Comment: but this i adds everything value "2017" not only date. I have date on this format : 2017 Jun 25. How use now lib datetime?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. Can you update your post with more information? Do you *only* want '2017' to be counted **if** it's within a date format, or do you want it counted with any occurrence? What are you trying to do with lib datetime?

Comment: Added a comment under your main post. If you can add a delimiter between columns for future datasets, Pandas is the best way to work with these things.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count 2017 only if its in a date format, you can use `regex` to do that as the following:

```
import re
with open('xyz.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        count += len(re.findall(r'\s+(2017)\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d+', line))
    print count
```